# While loop in function not terminating

Tags: c++, while-loop

I know the answer is probably very simple, but I've nearly exhausted myself trying everything I know in c++, which isn't much. The first function works, to my knowledge, I just can't get the loop to terminate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

unsigned int reverseInt(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int rem, reverse;

    while(num > 0)
    {
        rem = num % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + rem;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return reverse;
}

unsigned int generateSequence(unsigned int num, ostream& out)
{
    unsigned int k = 0;

    while(num != 1)
    {
        num = num + 4;
        num = reverseInt(num);
        k++;
        out  << ", " << num;
    }
    out << endl;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Please make it a [mcve]. Not much is missing, but a `main` would be nice and you have to tell us what input you used

Comment: also explain what the code is supposed to do. Why do you expect the loop to terminate? How can adding `4` to `num` eventually make it equal to `1`? What if `num` starts as `5`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's not just adding 4, it's also reversing the number. Without the bug in `reverse`, it would reach 1 after 52 steps when `num` starts as 5.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems with the code

1. `reverse` variable is not getting initialized even once in function `reverseInt`.
2. `num` variable is not getting reduced to 1 and loop will not terminate.

Comment: "*So, i would say please describe what you want to do in each function then we will be able to help you better.*" The comment section would be a better place to put this remark. I know you are trying to help, but it is advised not to answer a question that isn't yet well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

While analyzing your logic it looks like you have a finite loop with higher outcome as number of digits increase.

Your application reduces number of digit when sum of 4 reaches a digit ending with 6, But since you have unsigned int type which has higher range.

Application will get timeout if you go reaches threshold number of digits which generate more outcome for compiler to exit, say 5 digit number as threshold Eg: 11111.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is mainly that `reverse` is not initialized, on at least clang and gcc this means `reverse` will be initialized with its maximum value (2^64).

This means your loop never finishes as num just gets bigger and bigger and bigger, you will have a lot of integer overflows but since num is assigned from the return value of `reverse`, num will never hit 1